# can i make Multiple FileStream objects to one file in the same time?

Tags: c#, filestream

why in fs2 object throw error ?? i already have written a FileShare.ReadWrite in fs object

```
     FileStream fs = new FileStream("hello.txt",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite,FileShare.ReadWrite);

        mama();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    static void mama()
    {
        FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("hello.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        fs2.Read(new byte[3], 0, 3);
    }
```

can any one tell me why this error ?

error = The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\iP\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication32\ConsoleApplication32\bin\Debug\hello.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're passing `FileShare.None` to the second call. If you change that to `FileShare.ReadWrite` to match the first call, you won't have that problem.

The reason for this is because the `FileStream` constructor calls [`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) underneath, and if you take a look at the documentation for that function, it states:

> You cannot request a sharing mode that conflicts with the access mode
>   that is specified in an existing request that has an open handle.
>   **CreateFile** would fail and the GetLastError function would return
>   **ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION**.

You already have an open handle from the first request using `FileAccess.ReadWrite` as the access mode, which conflicts with `FileShare.None` in the second call.

Answer (score 0):

Because your code never *closes* the file and has an open handle to it

If you can, always use the `using` statement, it will `flush` and `close` the file

```
using(var fs = new FileStream(...))
{
    // do stuff here
} // this is where the file gets flushed and closed
```

If 2 methods are working on the same file, pass the `FileStream` in

```
static void mama(FileStream fs )
{
    fs .Read(new byte[3], 0, 3);
}
```